# Find the solution to $u_t=u_{xx}-xu_x, u(x,0)=x^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the solution to

$$u_t=u_{xx}-xu_x, \quad u(x,0)=x^{2}$$

To apply separation of variables, let $u(x,t)= X(x)T(t)$, then 
$$u_t=u_{xx} - x u_{x} \implies XT' = X'' T - x X' T \implies \frac{T'}{T} = \frac{X'' - x X'}{X}$$

Let

\begin{align}
\frac{T'}{T} &= \frac{X''-xX'}{X} \\
&= k \\
\end{align}

which gives the two ODEs

\begin{align}
T' - kT &= 0 \\
X'' - x X' - k X &= 0
\end{align}

How do we proceed from here?

Comment: You divided by $T$, so you should get a term $xX'/T$. Watch out that step.

Comment: @Gibbs.........i edited

Comment: The next thing you need to do is determine the boundary conditions for the ODEs from your initial data.

Answer (score 1):

$$u_t=u_{xx}-xu_x \tag 1$$
Before starting the method of separation of variables, note that $u(x,y)=C$=constant is solution of the PDE. If fact, you are looking for particular solutions on the form $u(x,y)=X(x)T(t)+C$. Then we go directly to the continuation of your calculus.

The solutions of $X''-xX'-kX=0$ involve Hermite polynomials. But, even without knowing this, one can guess that $X(x)$ might be a simple second degree polynomial : $X(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ . Putting it into $X''-xX'-kX=0$ the identification leads to :
$$k=-2\quad;\quad b=0 \quad;\quad c=-a \quad\text{then}\quad X(x)=a(x^2-1)$$
$$u(x,t)=a(x^2-1)e^{-2t}+C$$

We determine $a$ and $C$ according to the condition $u(x,0)=x^2$

$a(x^2-1)+C=x^2$ leads to $a=1$ and $C=1$. The solution is :
$$u(x,t)=(x^2-1)e^{-2t}+1$$